# How to prepopulate checkboxlist using struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 and trying to fill data from the system to a checkboxlist, 
On submit i am sent a String Array which contains the "id" of the selected item 
["8","2","5"]

but if i pre populate that field in advance with the same string array - nothing appears ticked, what am i doing wrong?

the definition is as follows:

```
<html:checkboxlist list="userroleslist" listKey="id" listValue="description" name="userroleresponse" label="User Roles"/>
```

userroleslist contains the list containing the complete list of options
with the id being the value i use
and the description field as the displayed label (this all works)
userroleresponse is a String Array that is returned as ["8","2","5"] when ticked and submitted, but when prepopulated is not ticking the boxes on screen,

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602959/how-to-prepopulate-checkboxes-with-struts2-and-jquery) will certainly help, Also See `html:multibox` ,[example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2EE/StrutsCreatingtheController.htm)

Comment: not really i am doing that already,

Comment: Off-topic, but I'd recommend using the normal "s" for Struts 2 tags to avoid confusion with S1, particularly since a lot of S2 tags don't emit HTML :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `value` attribute to set the values to be turned on. Here, if you have a method in the action class with signature `String [] getUserroleresponse()`, change your tag as follows:

```
<html:checkboxlist list="userroleslist" listKey="id" listValue="description" name="userroleresponse" label="User Roles" value="userroleresponse"/>
```

Moreover, make sure that the data-type of listKey should match with the value array provided. For e.g., if `id` is of type `String`, the value array should be of type `String []`.

You may refer the following link for an example:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/

Comment: tried that, didnt work, the question is i am putting "2" "5" "8" into the string array, as this is what is returned when submitting, but its not ticking the boxes do i need to add the description instead?

Comment: What is the datatype of bean property 'id'?

Comment: Theresa, I believe that the id property is of something other than String. In this case, you will need to change the datatype of id to String or change the userroleresponse array to that of type id. I have tested this and it works for me. Suppose if your the id property is int, make userroleresponse an array of int. That's all and it will work. Cheers!

Comment: James thanks that worked, maybe edit your answer and put that the rolesresponse needs to be the same type as the listkey for it to work.